# Работа с csv файлом - Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

Всем привет! Недавно начала изучать ruby, решаю домашку:
В csv файле хрянятся температурные показатели за каждый день в виде:

```
30.01, -7
31.01, -10
01.02, 0
```

...и т.д

Распарсить файл, посчитать и вывести среднюю температуру за каждый месяц. Проверка кода через rubocop

```
CSV.read('/home/natasha/Документы/CSV/temperature.csv') #вывожу даные  из csv файла в irb консоль
#наверное это не очень правильно, но не знаю, как обратиться к массиву
array =   [["1.01", "0"], ["2.01", "4"], ["3.01", "1"], ["4.01", "0"], ["5.01", "3"], ["6.01", "-12"], ["7.01", "-14"], ["8.01", "-8"], ["9.01", "-3"], ["10.01", "-1"], ["11.01", "-5"], ["12.01", "-5"], ["13.01", "4"], ["14.01", "2"], ["15.01", "-3"], ["16.01", "-7"], ["17.01", "-6"], ["18.01", "-7"], ["19.01", "-2"], ["20.01", "0"], ["21.01", "0"], ["22.01", "0"], ["23.01", "-2"], ["24.01", "-3"], ["25.01", "-9"], ["26.01", "-4"], ["27.01", "-4"], ["28.01", "-3"], ["29.01", "-9"], ["30.01", "-8"], ["31.01", "-8"], ["1.02", "-6"], ["2.02", "-3"], ["3.02", "-1"], ["4.02", "1"], ["5.02", "-2"], ["6.02", "-5"], ["7.02", "-10"], ["8.02", "-12"], ["9.02", "-7"], ["10.02", "-6"], ["11.02", "-5"], ["12.02", "-5"], ["13.02", "-3"], ["14.02", "0"], ["15.02", "1"], ["16.02", "1"], ["17.02", "1"], ["18.02", "4"], ["19.02", "2"], ["20.01", "1"], ["21.02", "4"], ["2.02", "6"], ["23.02", "5"], ["24.02", "12"], ["25.02", "2"]] 

array1 = array.flatten #"сплющиваю массив"
#=>["1.01", "0", "2.01", "4", "3.01", "1", "4.01", "0", "5.01", "3", "6.01", "-12", "7.01", "-14", "8.01", "-8", "9.01", "-3", "10.01", "-1", "11.01", "-5", "12.01", "-5", "13.01", "4", "14.01", "2", "15.01", "-3", "16.01", "-7", "17.01", "-6", "18.01", "-7", "19.01", "-2", "20.01", "0", "21.01", "0", "22.01", "0", "23.01", "-2", "24.01", "-3", "25.01", "-9", "26.01", "-4", "27.01", "-4", "28.01", "-3", "29.01", "-9", "30.01", "-8", "31.01", "-8", "1.02", "-6", "2.02", "-3", "3.02", "-1", "4.02", "1", "5.02", "-2", "6.02", "-5", "7.02", "-10", "8.02", "-12", "9.02", "-7", "10.02", "-6", "11.02", "-5", "12.02", "-5", "13.02", "-3", "14.02", "0", "15.02", "1", "16.02", "1", "17.02", "1", "18.02", "4", "19.02", "2", "20.01", "1", "21.02", "4", "2.02", "6", "23.02", "5", "24.02", "12", "25.02", "2"]
```

Не судите строго. Помогите, пожалуйста, скажите, правильным путем ли я иду. Я просто не знаю, как мне сделать дальше. Я думала, может достать из массива целые числа, и потом посчитать среднее арифметическое по ним. Вобщем, честно говоря, я запуталась, уже второй день сижу и никак не могу додуматься.

Comment: А с какой целью вы сплющили массив-то?

Answer (score 2):

Разбейте задачу на несколько маленьких подзадач:

1. Извлечь последние элементы внутренних массивов `["25.02", "2"] => "2"`
2. Преобразовать строку в число `"2" => 2`
3. Получить массив последних элементов массива массива
4. Подсчитать сумму элементов массива
5. Получить среднее арифметическое

Это называется декомпозиция, объяснить и научить этому очень сложно, преподаватели стремятся, чтобы вы пришли к этому сами. Не получается сразу - ничего страшного, со временем придет, главное руки не опускайте, но старайтесь дробить сложную задачу на части.

Теперь последовательно решайте каждую из этих задач. У вас уже есть массив, состоящий из массивов

```
array =  [["1.01", "0"], ["2.01", "4"], ..., ["25.02", "2"]]
```

Вам требуется получить массив последних элементов внутренних массивов. Не решайте задачу сразу в лоб. Берите отдельный элемент, например, `["25.02", "2"]` и работайте с ним. В Ruby все является объектом, чтобы воспользоваться его методами нужно знать класс. Уверены, не уверены в названии класса, на первых порах всегда проверяйте названия класса

```
["25.02", "2"].class # Array
```

Даже если вы знаете некоторые методы класса `Array`, все-равно идете в документацию http://ruby-doc.org. Вводите в поле класса название `Array`, попадаете на страницу [Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/) и знакомитесь с его методами, до тех пор, пока там не останется чего-то, чего бы вы не помнили без обращения к документации. Ищите методы для решения вашей задачи. В частности вы там обнаружите методы [first](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-first) и [last](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-last), которые извлекают первый и последний элемент массива. Например

```
["25.02", "2"].last # "2"
```

Пробуем сложить две строки - получаем странный результат - это явно не то

```
"2" + "5" # 25
```

Строки конкатенируются, вместо сложения чисел, нам надо явно привести строки к целым числам. На всякий случай смотрим класс, который действительно оказывается строкой

```
"2".class # String
```

Идем в документацию класса [String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html) и читаем все от начала до конца. Делаем так до тех пор, пока там не будет знакомо абсолютно все. Находим метод для преобразования в число [to_i](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-to_i). Пробуем

```
"2".to_i + "5".to_i # 7
```

Получилось то, что требовалось. Теперь получаем массив, состоящий из последних элементов массива, преобразованных к целому числу. Для решения задачи вам нужно, как минимум пройтись циклом по полученному массиву. В Ruby циклы использовать не принято, почти все задачи решаются при помощи итераторов. Могу предположить, что именно использование итераторов вызывает у вас сложности. К сожалению или счастью, программировать на Ruby без понимания итераторов не получится, их придется освоить на уровне полного понимания (как переменные, циклы и условные операторы в других языках).

Для того, чтобы получить массив последних элементов, мы можем воспользоваться итератором `collect`, который проходит по всем элементам коллекции и предоставляет блок, результат вычисления в котором становится соответствующим элементом новой коллекции

```
array =  [["1.01", "0"], ["2.01", "4"], ["25.02", "2"]]
array.collect { |x| x.last } # ["0", "4", "2"]
```

За счет `to_proc` метода можно сократить приведенную выше конструкцию до

```
array =  [["1.01", "0"], ["2.01", "4"], ["25.02", "2"]]
array.collect(&:last) # ["0", "4", "2"]
```

Это не синтаксический сахар, это способ передачи блока, при котором к символу `:last` неявно применяется метод `to_proc` (приемы работы с блоками нужно понимать так же хорошо, как и итераторы)

```
array =  [["1.01", "0"], ["2.01", "4"], ["25.02", "2"]]
array.collect { |x| :last.to_proc.call(x) } # ["0", "4", "2"]
```

При выборе решения, помните, что как и в лингвистическом языке, в программировании предпочтение отдается наиболее короткой конструкции.

Теперь когда мы получили массив строк, их нужно преобразовать в целое число

```
array =  [["1.01", "0"], ["2.01", "4"], ["25.02", "2"]]
array.collect(&:last).collect(&:to_i) # [0, 4, 2]
```

Теперь стоит задача суммировать элементы массива и получить одно число. Можно воспользоваться готовым методом [`sum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sum)

```
array =  [["1.01", "0"], ["2.01", "4"], ["25.02", "2"]]
array.collect(&:last).collect(&:to_i).sum # 6
```

Однако, в учебных целях имеет смысл освоить итератор `inject` или `each_with_object` (в них важно разобраться, вы будете встречать их часто в чужом коде, поэтому нужно хорошо понимать, почему они себя так ведут)

```
array =  [["1.01", "0"], ["2.01", "4"], ["25.02", "2"]]
array.collect(&:last).collect(&:to_i).inject(0){ |x, m| x + m } # 6
array.collect(&:last).collect(&:to_i).inject(&:+) # 6
```

Теперь соберите эти кирпичики в единую программу, получив сумму элементов и потом среднее, прогнав код рабочей программы через Rubocop (желательно останавливаясь на всех замечаниях и прорабатывая их).

На самом деле эти задачи на многократное чтение документации и освоение техник работы с итераторами и блоками. Очень важно их решать, постоянно обращаясь к документации, многократно читая ее снова и снова. Об этом почти не рассказывают в книгах, об этом редко говорят, но поверьте все именно так и делают, когда станете звездой программирования - будете черпать информацию из исходного кода, однако пока у вас есть сложности при решении учебных заданий, при любом затыке обращайтесь к документации и читайте ее от начала до конца. Тем более в случае Ruby документация преотличная.